# Differentiate CSS style based on element it's applied to

Tags: css, html, sass

Is there an easy way to differentiate styles based on the element it is applied to? For example:

```
.myclass div { background-color: red; }
.myclass span { background-color: green; }
```

The above works when the elements are nested. My desired functionality is:

```
<div class="myclass"> ..red background </div>
<span class="myclass"> ..green background </span>
```

Not looking for a JS solution. Pure CSS/html.

Comment: simply read more about CSS selector ...

Comment: wow another negative rating. you guys rock...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```css
div.myclass  { background-color: red; }
span.myclass { background-color: green; }
```

```html
<div class="myclass">red background</div>
<span class="myclass">green background</span>
```